# CloudKit integration does not support unique constraints. The following entities are constrained:

Tags: xcode, core-data, cloudkit

CloudKit integration does not support unique constraints. The following entities are constrained:

I'm trying to create cloudkit to my application integrated with existing CoreData

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xehyZ.png)

Comment: The error message is pretty clear. You can’t have a unique value constraint on a property if you want to use CloudKit. Core Data supports them but only for local stores.